# jquery datepicker getting dateText out of onSelect event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

want to get dateText from datepicker out of onSelect event, in some other function:

example:

when in onSelect event:

```
dateText is equal to 08.02.2011
```

$('#datetime').datepicker("getDate") returns:

```
Tue Feb 08 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Russia Standard Time)
```

so it can not enter to my controller properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datepicker getDate  method return Date object ([Date object reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)) you need to convert it

```
function convert(date) {
   return date.getDate() + "."+ (date.getMonth()+1) + "." + date.getFullYear();
}
```

You can also try to overwrite toString method of Date object, but I don't know how this will work with DatePicker plugin.

```
Date.prototype.toString = function() {
   return this.getDate() + "."+ (this.getMonth()+1) + "." + this.getFullYear();
}
```